# Find the movie with the largest cast, out of the list of movies that have a review

Tags: cypher

Can someone please assist me on how to write a query that will return the following:
"Find the movie with the largest cast, out of the list of movies that have a review."
OUTPUT: movie_title, number_of_cast_members

using this database https://neo4j.com/developer/movie-database/

This needs to be written in Cypher.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neo4J Cypher - Count Relationships of Matched Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652594/neo4j-cypher-count-relationships-of-matched-nodes)

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (:Actor)-[:ACTS_IN]->(m:Movie)<-[:RATED]-()
with m, count(*) AS actor_count order by actor_count desc
return m.title, actor_count limit 1
```

1. `MATCH` the pattern you search (actors that acts in a movie that have a rating)
2. Use an aggregation function to count the numbers of actors (`count(*)`) and group them by Movie (`with m`)
3. `ORDER` the result by the count descendingly `desc`
4. Return the title and the count of the first item `limit 1`. As the list is ordered with the most largest cast first, limiting the result to the first item gives the largest cast.

Note: if two movies have the same size of casting, only one is returned.

Comment: You should add some explanation to your answer.